# How can we join 2 vertices in gremlin and get the desired output

Tags: node.js, gremlin

I have vertex called  "test" and "check"

test has fields like

```
g.V().hasLabel('test').valueMap(true).toList();
```

{ 'id': ['3130'],  'label': 'dev',  'mdate': ['2021-02-27T13:52:16.494Z'],  'mby': ['sync'],
'id': 'e8bbf1e1-7240-b5f2-cd55-b8558b02a93f',  'bName': ['STG '] }

check has fields like

```
 g.V().hasLabel('check').valueMap(true).toList();
```

{ 'label': 'stag', 'mdate': ['2021-02-27T13:52:15.817Z'], 'mby': ['Test'],  'vname': ['STROE GMBH'], 'vnum': ['170010'],
'id': 'dcbbf1e1-70f9-aeff-828e-130be0186d81' }

how can we join both vertex and get the output data like below using gremlin query

{ 'id': '',  'label': '',  'mdate': '',  'mby': '',  'id':'', 'name':'', 'vname':'', 'vnum': '' }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by getting their `elementMap` and using a `group` step to merge the results. I included an example that uses the air routes data set so you can see the output format. I also added a version that should work with the data you provided.

```
gremlin> g.V(3,4).elementMap().unfold().group().by(keys).by(values)

==>[country:[US,US],code:[AUS,BNA],longest:[12250,11030],city:[Austin,Nashville],lon:[-97.6698989868164,-86.678199768
0664],type:[airport,airport],elev:[542,599],icao:[KAUS,KBNA],id:[3,4],label:[airport,airport],region:[US-TX,US-TN],ru
nways:[2,4],lat:[30.1944999694824,36.1245002746582],desc:[Austin Bergstrom International Airport,Nashville Internatio
nal Airport]]
```

Using your example you could do

```
g.V().hasLabel('test','check').
      elementMap().
      unfold().
      group().
        by(keys).
        by(values)
```

Comment: this query works fine and it returns all the fields , but is there way we can select only required fields using the above same query?

Comment: When you say 'select only required fields' I assume you want to limit the fields returned by the `elementMap` step? If so there are a couple of options. `elementMap` can take names of properties you want returned such as `elementMap('name')`. If you do not want the ID and label included you can always switch to using `valueMap` or `valueMap().by(unfold())` which can also take parameters. The latter form unrolls property values so they look more like the `elementMap` results.